# Is it possible to connect this wall light to the existing fixture?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I recently discovered a couple of what look like wall light fixtures in my apartment so I went out and bought a wall light hoping the connection would be relatively simple.

The fixture looks like this:

[image]

The wall looks like this:

[image: wall light]

Can I connect the two together easily or should I call on an electrician?

Comment: Do you know that the colour code for the house wires, i.e., which is neutral and which hot?  Do you know the meaning of "L" and "N" on the connection block?  Do you have the captions for the two pictures reversed?

Comment: BROWN to the LIVE (L) terminal
BLUE to the NEUTRAL (N) terminal
GREEN/YELLOW to the EARTH (E) terminal

Comment: Did you swap the pictures by mistake?

Comment: The OP evidently has a different definition of "fixture" from the normal US one. This may be the standard UK definition or it may be his own one. He is using "fixture" to refer to the components *fixed* to the wall. In the US we use light "fixture" to refer to the luminaire which is to be attached to the wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off the power at the wall switch. If there are others in house while you are doing this, tape the switch in the off position or attach a note to it, and inform all others in the house that they are not to flip this switch while you are working on it. Safer yet is to turn off the breaker to this circuit in the consumer unit.

The black coloured connection block looks like it is in the light fixture and, if so, I suggest you use it. Remove the other connector from the brown and blue coloured wires and insert them into the appropriate holes in the black block, and secure them with the screws (firm tight but not so tight you break anything). Insert the earthing wires in the middle hole and secure. Test by turning on the wall switch.